# when I train my network ,It got an errror, Expected target size (4, 224), got torch.Size([4, 224, 224])

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

In my train.py

```
criteon = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = criteon(binary_output_c1,labels)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

both binary_output_c1,labels size are [4, 224,224], 4 means batchsize, 224 means h and w.
and it got error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-78553e2886de>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/experiment_code/U-net/train.py', wdir='F:/experiment_code/U-net')
  File "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "D:\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "F:/experiment_code/U-net/train.py", line 77, in <module>
    loss = criteon(binary_output_c1,labels)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 942, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2056, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1881, in nll_loss
    out_size, target.size()))
ValueError: Expected target size (4, 224), got torch.Size([4, 224, 224])
```

I don't know if it is possible to use 3D tensor in crossentropyloss,this network use to Semantic segmentation

I make my label'size to [4,256,224,224] where 256 is the number of classes. code is here

```
model.train()
outputs = model(imgs)   # output  B * C * H *W
output_c1 = outputs[:,1,:,:] # 2 channels ,I choose the second channel
Rounding_output_c1 = torch.round(output_c1)
labelss =  torch.stack([(labels == i).long() for i in range(256)])
labelss = labelss.permute(1,0,2,3)
Rounding_output_c11 = torch.stack([(Rounding_output_c1 == i).float() for i in range(256)])
Rounding_output_c11 = Rounding_output_c11.permute(1,0,2,3)
loss = criteon(Rounding_output_c11,labelss)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
```

It get error too

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/experiment_code/U-net/train_2.py", line 76, in <module>
    loss = criteon(Rounding_output_c11,labelss)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 942, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2056, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1873, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: 1only batches of spatial targets supported (non-empty 3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [4, 256, 224, 224]
```

Comment: what is the shape of your prediction `binary_output_c1`? is it possible it is also of shape `4x224x224`? it should be `4xCx224x224` where `C` is the number of classes

Comment: **binary_out** size is [4,224,224] ,@Shai

Comment: `outputs=model(imgs)` ,where **outputs** size is [4,2,224,224],4 means batchsize,2 means channel, 224 means h and w. when I use `loss  = criteon(outputs,labels)` it get error too,

Comment: what is the error you get now? is it the same error? what is the size and type of `labels`?

Comment: i use this code `loss = criteon(outputs,labels.long())`,but i get another error .`RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
THCudaCheck FAIL file=..\aten\src\THC\THCCachingHostAllocator.cpp line=265 error=59 : device-side assert triggered`

Comment: seems like GPU memory issue. try reducing batch size from 4 to 2

Comment: thanks .it get the same error , It could not be my GPU problem, this dataset is very small.

Comment: How to wrap lines in comments

Comment: you do not wrap lines in comments - you simply edit your post, properly formatted.

Comment: @ Shai thanks, I have edited my post,but it get  an error too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) then your prediction should have two channels: one for predicting `0` and another for predicting `1`. This is a bit redundant, but the loss expects the prediction to have #channels == #labels.

Alternatively, you can concat the prediction before passing to loss:

```
loss = criteon(torch.cat((-binary_output_c1[:, None, ...], binary_output_c1[:, None,...]), dim=1),labels)
```

Comment: thanks , I use your code ,but also get an error `RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered` `THCudaCheck FAIL file=..\aten\src\THC\THCCachingHostAllocator.cpp line=265 error=59 : device-side assert triggered`